# Is JBoss Fuse available under an open source license?

Tags: open-source, licensing, redhat, fuseesb

I've been attempting to find a location from which to download Fuse, but all the links in the Red Hat site seem to indicate that the freely downloadable version of the product is available "for development purposes only". Is there a download location that clearly identifies it as an open source version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> JBoss Fuse is open source licensed with the ASL 2.0 license.
>
> You can download and use the product for free for development purpose.
>   But if you want to use it for production, then you need a subscription

Claus, could you clarify this a little?

I was under (false?) assumption that ASL2.0 means that use of the software is free. Free regardless of if its for development or production use. At least http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html points me in that direction. How can JBoss fuse be ASL2.0 and at the same time forbid use for prodution?

It would also help if I could find out clear license terms somewhere. If I look at http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse or https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/JBoss_Fuse/ I cannot see the license specification. Where can I view the actual license terms of Jboss Fuse?

Comment: ASL license does not mandate the software to be free. The products from Apache Software Foundation is free, accordingly to their FAQ. But any other project/vendor is free to decide if his software is free or not, with and without using the ASL license of their software etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... Do you know where I can view the exact licensing information of JBoss Fuse?

Comment: The JBoss developer terms is here (eg for all JBoss products for development purpose) - http://www.jboss.org/developer-program/termsandconditions

Answer (score 4):

JBoss Fuse is open source licensed with the ASL 2.0 license.

You can download and use the product for *free* for development purpose. But if you want to use it for production, then you need a subscription.

What you ask about is free software. That is a totally different thing than whether or not the source code is open or closed.

Answer (score -1):

According to my understand of this document, the "open source versión" not exist.
Must I install Apache CXF, Apache Camel, Apache ActiveMQ, and Apache Karaf individually?

https://www.redhat.com/resourcelibrary/whitepapers/jboss-enterprise-middleware-community-to-enterprise-whitepaper

Comment: This is plain wrong! There is a big difference between free software and whether the source code is open or closed. If you want free software then, ex all the Apache projects is both free and open source software, eg also abbreviated as FOSS.